# jQuery DataTable Header row issue while allowing sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, datatables

I had converted the `ASP.NET GridView` into `jQuery DataTable`.

I want to apply `jQuery DataTable` to allow sorting. But while I'm assigning `"bSort":true,` it's showing `dataTable`.

`SORRY AS I'M NEW HERE I'M NOT ALLOWED TO POST IMAGES YET.`

But what my problem is one more row is added under the `thead` (with the same `CSS`) and when I click on particular column only that `CSS` gets disappear. But row will still there.

I've tried following code for this `datatable`.

```
function pageLoad() {
            var r;
            if ($('#ctl00_CPHLAMBDA_GrdSampleSaved').length != 0) {
                debugger;
                r = $('#<%= GrdSampleSaved.clientid %> tr:first')
                $('#<%= GrdSampleSaved.clientid %> tr:first').remove();
                $('#<%= GrdSampleSaved.clientid %>').prepend($('<thead>').append(r));
            }
            var bTable = $('#<%= GrdSampleSaved.clientid %>').dataTable({
                "bStateSave": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bSort": true,
                "bDestory": true,
                "bRetrieve": true

            });

            //$('#<%= GrdSampleSaved.clientid %> tbody tr:first').remove();
        }
```

### HTML

```
<div id="divGrd">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GrdSample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="True"
                            SkinID="grdViewSmlAutoSize" Style="width: 100%; margin-top: 2%;" AllowPaging="true"
                            PageSize="10">
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3A87AD" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataFormatString="number" HeaderText="Sr No">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="5%" Wrap="true" />
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="5%" Wrap="true" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="vSampleId" HeaderText="Sample ID">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="true" Width="8%" />
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="8%" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="vSampleType" HeaderText="Sample Type">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="true" Width="20%" />
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="20%" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="dBirthDate" HeaderText="D.O.B." DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"
                                    HtmlEncode="false">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="8%" Wrap="true" />
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="8%" Wrap="true" />
                                </asp:BoundField>--%>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
```

I'm using vb.net for coding.

Comment: How does your markup / HTML looks like?

Comment: @davidkonrad : My Markup/HTML is just like simple `gridview` with `databound` option. Where I get the problem is in this `datatable` section. It's getting one more blank header row by itself.